# Определить какой конкретно метод выбросил исключение

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Для Primary Key написал вот такой код для обработки исключений. Но у меня есть три таблицы и три уникальных ключа. Как понять какой из них дал это исключение, чтобы пометить эту область красным цветом?

```
try
{

}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    if (ex.Number == 2627)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Տվյալ համարի կենդանի արդեն գրանցված է...");                    
    }
}
```

вот конструкция БД

```sql
CREATE TABLE Animals(
        number int NOT NULL,
        //прочие поля
        motherNumber int ,
        FOREIGN KEY (motherNumber) REFERENCES MotherAnimal(motherNumber),
        fatherNumber int ,
        FOREIGN KEY (fatherNumber) REFERENCES FatherAnimal(fatherNumber),
        CONSTRAINT PK_number PRIMARY KEY (number)
)

Create Table MotherAnimal(
    motherNumber int not null,
    //Прочие поля
    CONSTRAINT PK_motherNumber PRIMARY KEY (motherNumber)
    )
Create Table FatherAnimal(
    fatherNumber int not null,
    //Прочие поля
    CONSTRAINT PK_fatherNumber PRIMARY KEY (fatherNumber)
    )
```

код на C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BandivanKatDataContext db = new BandivanKatDataContext();
    try
    {
        MotherAnimal newMotherAnimal = new MotherAnimal();
        //
        db.MotherAnimal.InsertOnSubmit(newMotherAnimal);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        //
        FatherAnimal newFatherAnimal = new FatherAnimal();

        db.FatherAnimal.InsertOnSubmit(newFatherAnimal);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        Animals newAnimal = new Animals();
        db.Animals.InsertOnSubmit(newAnimal);
        db.SubmitChanges();    

        //
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Number == 2627)
        {
            if (ex.Source == "PK_number")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("...");
                textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (ex.Source == "PK_motherNumber")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("...");
                textBox8.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
            else if (ex.Source == "PK_fatherNumber")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("...");
                textBox11.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }         

        }
    }
}
```

> {"Нарушено \"PK_number\" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект \"dbo.Animals\". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (1).\r\nВыполнение данной инструкции было прервано."}

Comment: в чем конкретно проблема то?!

Comment: нужно понять какой ключ дал исключение

Comment: @des1roer если translate.google.ru не ошибся то Армянский, если я правильно понял то Вы пытаетесь писать что то для гостиницы, и у Вас система не должна позволит зарегистрировать нескольких постояльцев в одном номере?

Comment: Если ограничениям Primary Key давать соответствующие имена, то по этим именам в сообщении об ошибке можно узнать, где произошло исключение.

Comment: @ msi  а как давать имена?

Comment: @Bald56rus нет эта программа для молочного завода,и нужно что когда добавляется новый теленок ,в таблице матерей допускалось регистрация коровы который уже зарегистрирована,по скольку одна корова может иметь несколько теленок

Comment: а разве в блоке `try` Вы не знаете куда пишите?! Вы же пишете в конкретную таблицу, если я не ошибаюсь в исключении есть информация о дубликате, т.е. Вы в блоке `catch` знаете где произошло исключение и в связи с какой записью

Comment: что еще за ограничения primary key? опишите полностью задачу. а чтобы у теленка можно было указать единственную мать, есть foreign key. при этом будет гарантировано что мать одна и она есть.

Comment: что бы можно было открыть вопрос и дать Вам ответ приведите структуру бд касающуюся вопроса, и код

Comment: @Bald56rus вот написал все на вопросе,только там из `ex` не могу получить нужная сообщения

Comment: приведите код `Exception`

Comment: {"Нарушено \"PK_number\" ограничения PRIMARY KEY. Не удается вставить повторяющийся ключ в объект \"dbo.Animals\". Повторяющееся значение ключа: (1).\r\nВыполнение данной инструкции было прервано."}___вот только не говорит об этом просто не записывает и все

Comment: посмотрите мой ответ, пишите что непонятно попытаюсь помочь

Comment: `InsertOnSubmit`? Это точно EF? Больше похоже на Linq2Sql...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

как это сделано у Вас:

при создании экземпляра `child` Вы создаете *родителей* в этот момент может возникнуть исключение, которое Вы хотите отловить и сообщить пользователю.
если уж делаете так то проверяйте наличие в базе перед попыткой создать например как то так:

```
var mother = //создаете объект;
var result = db.Mothers.Where()//делаете запрос к бд
if (result.Count()==0)
    db.Mothers.Insert();//вставляете только в случае отсутствия в бд;
//либо делаете блок else в котором информируете пользователя
```

аналогично проверяете второго родителя.

минусы создания *родителей* сразу с *ребенком* в таком подходе как у Вас: опечатка, и вот имеем дублирование, этого конечно можно избежать написав логику проверки, но наполнять справочники лучше узкому кругу лиц

Я так до конца и не понял логики Вашего приложения, попробую написать как бы это сделал я

```
public class Mother
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие поля
}

public class Father
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //прочие поля
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int MotherId {get;set;}
    public int FatherId {get;set;}
}
```

`Mother` и `Father` наполняются по мере необходимости из отдельных форм плюс логика дабы избежать дублирования т.е. это справочники;

`Child` я бы сделал так:

форма в которой создается *ребенок* выбираются родители из списка заполненного ранее, плюс какая то дополнительная информация, т.е. прежде чем создать *ребенка* в случае нового/новых *родителей* заполняете справочник и потом только создаете *ребенка*.

P.S.: если же Вы все таки решите оставить так есть то тогда можно анализировать текст возникшего исключения

UPD.:

В том тексте который был приведен видно что исключение происходит при попытке добавить повторяющуюся запись в `dbo.Animals` и указан `id` записи.

самый простой вариант это как то так:

```
try
{}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    if(ex.Message.Contains("Animals"))
    {
    }
    else if(ex.Message.Contains("MotherAnimals"))
    {
    }
    //ну и так далее
}
```

Но все таки я бы рекомендовал добавить хоть немного логики: т.е. перед добавлением проверять на наличие в бд

Comment: @ Bald56rus   и как анализировать этот текст ??не хочу всю программу менять ради этого ,кажется я уже достал своими вопросами,но если не сложно можешь код написать?

Comment: @VardanVardanyan обновил ответ